# Why use Intent when we can directly use modified static members?

Tags: android, android-intent, static

Suppose we are sending a data received from text-box from an activity Main_Activity to another activity Display_Message_Activity by clicking a button.

In Main_Activity:
Step-1: To declare the final String

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

Step-2: To assign the click to the button

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Step-3: In DisplayMessageActivity,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Get the message from the intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
}
```

Now my Question is why should we use **intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);** ??
Instead of that, we can easily update the value of static String **MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE** on button click and then directly access it and assign the value of EXTRA_MESSAGE string to the **message* String in DisplayMessageActivity. 
I mean,
step:1

```
 public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

step:2

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
EXTRA_MESSAGE=message;
startActivity(intent);
}
```

step:3

```
.
.
.
String message=MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
.
.
.
```

Then why usage of Intent is preferred in case of message passing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Android kills and restarts the process for your application, then the static variables will get assigned to their default values. You might be better of using SharedPreferences instead of static variables if you want values to persist.

Using static variables is not recommended. Static variables are stored in a PermGen section of the heap. Even if the class finishes it works the static variables stays in the heap. The garbage collector does mark and sweep. If you have a static variables in the 1st activity which is referenced in the 2nd activity, the reference stays long.

You might get memory leaks if your using more static variables. Also reduce use of unnecessary objects.

**Static variables are referenced by Class objects which are referenced by ClassLoaders -so unless either the ClassLoader drops the Class somehow or the ClassLoader itself becomes eligible for garbage collection the static variables won't be garbage collected.** So if you are using static variables referenced in many class those classes and the one in which static variables are declared cannot be garbage collected unless those classes are available for garbage collection. So this leads to heap memory expanding leading to memory leaks.

To pass data (primitives types) between activities , i recommend using intents.

In this video the guy talks about why static variables should not be used and how to avoid memory leaks.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html. Check the topic under Use Static Final For Constants.

**Its not that you should not use static variables.**

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3.

Check the topic under **How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application?**

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea for couple of reasons both from safety and design perspective.

Firstly, it can be unsafe in the case where your process is restarted transparently by the ActivityManager (e.g due to RAM pressure). In that case all your statics are reinitialized.

Secondly, intents are android way to start components intra and inter process and potentially pass data across process boundaries. In the case of going across process boundaries, the static solution will obviously not work.

In your example, DisplayMessageActivity is started within the same process but what if tomorrow you decide that it should accept intents from other apps. Then you will have to go back and pass the "data the right way". Why not start with the "right way" and make it future proof?

Answer (score 1):

In case when you are using `static String` to pass data the memory leak is not significant, but there is something more important:

When you press HOME on the second activity and your process is killed by the system, after you go back you will not see the value of a `static String` what you set before (it will be `null` or what value you set it as default), but you will get the value from the `Intent` you passed. This works because system persists this value.